# What exactly does weapon weight affects?

Tags: mercenary-kings

Weapon you use has weight, and of course it changes depending on which parts you use.

What exactly does the weapon weight affect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in the [Penny Arcade Forum](http://forums.penny-arcade.com/discussion/181191/i-wanna-talk-about-mercenary-kings)

> Finally, weight.
>
> The weight of your weapon, your installed bionic mods (walk to the
> left, talk to Ms. Lab Coat), your KNOIFE (you'll unlock access to this
> middle of Tier 1) and your backpack gear decide how fast you move. The
> heavier your gun, the slower you move, the more mods you have
> installed, the slower you move. Two mods, a spear, some grenades and
> medkits, plus a kitted out bringer of dakka... you'll be pretty slow.
> Carry just a handgun, a stiletto, no mods, and a couple of adrenaline
> shots, and you'll be pretty speedy. It's up to you how fast you wanna
> run around. I get by just fine moving at Normal to Very Slow. Your
> armor has no weight, and upgrading it is pure bonus.

TL;DR - Seems like it affects your movement speed